# Detect text similarities between different topic models

Tags: r, quanteda

In a topic modeling approach where we have 2 different results of topic models like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(stm)
library(janeaustenr)
library(tidytext)

library(quanteda)
testDfm <- gadarian$open.ended.response %>%
    tokens(remove_punct = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE, remove_symbols = TRUE)  %>%
    dfm()
    
out <- convert(testDfm, to = "stm")
documents <- out$documents
vocab <- out$vocab
meta <- out$meta

topic_model1 <- stm(documents = out$documents, vocab = out$vocab, K = 5)
topic_model2 <- stm(documents = out$documents, vocab = out$vocab, K = 3)
```

let's call them topic_model1 and topic_model2(maybe it could be better to use a different data input but the gadarian dataset was the most easy for reproducability reasons).

Is there any way to [compare the text results](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-62362-3_12) of the two models and provide some kind of meta analysis or create any diagram to compare the topics of the two models?

Answer (score 3):

the comparision of the two models is a bit tricky - because we have word, topics, the two models and of course the beta value. A simple chart to visualize one model would be this:

```
library(tidytext)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

tidytext::tidy(topic_model2) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(topic) %>% 
  dplyr::slice_max(beta, n = 5) %>% # just the top 5 beta values to keep the plot readable
  ggplot2::ggplot(aes(reorder(term, beta), beta))+
  ggplot2::geom_col() +
  ggplot2::coord_flip() +
  ggplot2::facet_wrap(~topic)
```

[image]

This approach can be used and refined to make heatmaps per model side by side:

```
tidytext::tidy(topic_model1) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(topic) %>% 
  dplyr::slice_max(beta, n = 5) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(MODEL = "K5") %>% 
  dplyr::union(tidytext::tidy(topic_model2) %>% 
                     dplyr::group_by(topic) %>% 
                     dplyr::slice_max(beta, n = 5) %>% 
                     dplyr::mutate(MODEL = "K3") ) %>% 
  ggplot2::ggplot(aes(topic, term, fill = beta)) +
  ggplot2::geom_tile() +
  ggplot2::facet_wrap(~MODEL)
```

[image]

You can look at this tutorial and the cases to get some inspirations: https://www.tidytextmining.com/topicmodeling.html